# Is it possible to control the bounciness in Rigid Body?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I was trying to make 3 balls bounce at a time from same height with same weight and same bounciness. But when they collide with the passive surface they start to bounce unevenly like one goes very high other one bounces very low and gradually they change direction while bouncing.

Comment: Can't reproduce, all bounce the same with the same settings. Have you tried reproducing it in a new scene with only the balls and the surface? Have you tried setting the balls shapes to "Sphere"? Have you tried baking the simulation?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed it was a bug in Blender 2.8 Beta. Later it worked properly.

Comment: Rather than answering, perhaps consider deleting both this answer and the question.

Answer (score 1):

im using 2.80 and it work. just set the bounciness in rigid body ACTIVE and PASSIVE between 0.5
[image]
[image]